# Getting values of checked checkboxes, already checked items are re-added

Tags: javascript

I need all values of the `checked` `checkboxes` of this list:

```
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.40"> 0.40</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.50"> 0.50</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.60"> 0.60</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.70"> 0.70</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.80"> 0.80</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="6.00"> 6.00</a></li>
```

I want to store the `values` of the `checked` items in an `form field` separated by an `pipe`.

```
<input type="text" id="search_dikte_res" name="search_dikte_res" value="" readonly="readonly">
```

When I use this script then the value is (as expected) overwritten by the latest `checked` `checkbox` value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function search_multiple_dikte()
{
   var elems = document.getElementsByName('search_dikte');
   for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
   {
        if(elems[i].checked)
        {
            document.getElementById('search_dikte_res').value = elems[i].value;
        }
   }
}
</script>
```

So I have changed this so the existing content of the `formfield` is loaded, then adding a `pipe` and then the new value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function search_multiple_dikte()
{
   var elems = document.getElementsByName('search_dikte');
   for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
   {
        if(elems[i].checked)
        {
            document.getElementById('search_dikte_res').value = document.getElementById('search_dikte_res').value + '|' + elems[i].value;
        }
   }
}
</script>
```

**What I expect when I select `0.40` and `0.60` and `0.80` is `|0.40|0.60|0.80`**

What I get is when I select `0.40` is `|0.40`

Then I select `0.60` and then I am getting `|0.40|0.40|0.60`

Then adding `0.80` gives `|0.40|0.40|0.60|0.40|0.60|0.80`

The script is adding all selected values again, but when I use code `document.getElementById('search_dikte_res').value = elems[i].value;` getting only the latest value, so I am a bit confused now....

```js
function search_multiple_dikte()
{
   var elems = document.getElementsByName('search_dikte');
   for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
   {
        if(elems[i].checked)
        {
            document.getElementById('search_dikte_res').value = document.getElementById('search_dikte_res').value + '|' + elems[i].value;
        }
   }
}
```

```html
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.40"> 0.40</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.50"> 0.50</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.60"> 0.60</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.70"> 0.70</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.80"> 0.80</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="6.00"> 6.00</a></li>

<input type="text" id="search_dikte_res" name="search_dikte_res" value="" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: The problem is that you're always adding to value, without any reset

Answer (score 0):

Use your loop to populate an array then after the loop completes join that array to set the input value

```js
function search_multiple_dikte()
{
   const elems = document.getElementsByName('search_dikte'),
         valArray = [...elems].filter(el => el.checked).map(el => el.value);
   document.getElementById('search_dikte_res').value = valArray.join('|')
}
```

```html
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.40"> 0.40</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.50"> 0.50</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.60"> 0.60</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.70"> 0.70</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.80"> 0.80</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte()">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="6.00"> 6.00</a></li>

<input type="text" id="search_dikte_res" name="search_dikte_res" value="" readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function search_multiple_dikte(btn){
  var inputButton=btn.children[0]
  var thisButtonChecked=inputButton.checked;
  var buttonValue=inputButton.value;
  console.log([thisButtonChecked,buttonValue])
  //do whatever you want next with this info
  //also note that if you change inputButton.checked value manually, it will change the checked/not-checked situation in the button itself
}
```

```html
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte(this)">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.40"> 0.40</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte(this)">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.50"> 0.50</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte(this)">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.60"> 0.60</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte(this)">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.70"> 0.70</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte(this)">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="0.80"> 0.80</a></li>
<li onclick="search_multiple_dikte(this)">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="search_dikte" value="6.00"> 6.00</a></li>
```